# What do the card levels mean?

Tags: theatrhythm-final-fantasy

I've acquired several CollectaCards in my time playing *Theathrhythm*. Sometimes, I'll go check them out and read the neat little quotes in the Museum.

One thing that's piqued my interest is that these cards seem to have levels of some kind. For instance, my Warrior of Light card is **Lv. 3**, while my Cloud card is **Lv. 1**. Both of these cards are **Normal**.

[image]

**What does this information tell me?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you get a card you already have, that card goes up one level. They become holofoil cards at level 4, and platinum cards at level 7. The card levels are capped at 9, I believe.

Also, if you've noticed, the image on the card changes with each level!